# Is there a way to check for missed/unread notifications?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there an api in mango sdk that allows me to programatically poll the notifications/toast to at least get the count.  I'd like to write background service check for missed messages.

Comment: check this link for the new api's under mango, background code is one of them however i didn't seem to find anything to do with messages http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to get hold of the email/SMS messaging details like this in Windows Phone. The only way to interact with the email client is via the SDK Launchers and Choosers: [see this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769542%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

About all you can do is call the `EmailComposeTask` or `SmsComposeTask` for writing a plain text email or SMS, or `EmailAddressChooserTask` for getting an email address from the address book.

Also bear in mind that launchers and choosers must be initiated by a user action and cannot be launched from any background agent code.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question, which was about toast and tile notifications, not about SMS or email

Comment: @Marek: I wish that was clear from the question ;). I was working on "I'd like to write background service check for missed messages.". Otherwise the question is pointless - if you control a webservice that  raises toast and tiles via MPN, then just write code to query the count from that webservice...